# Creating and downloading an Excel file from ASPX page

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I need to create and excel file and download it from an aspx page. I created a simple page (default.aspx) with one button on it ("Button1"). Here is the default.aspx.cs file

```
using System;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string content = "";
        content += "<head>";
        content += "</head>";
        content += "<body>";
        content += "<table>";
        content += "<tr>";
        content += "<th>foo</th>";
        content += "</tr>";
        content += "</table>";
        content += "</body>";
        content += "</html>";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test.xls");
        Response.Write(content);
    }
}
```

When I run this code and click on the button it does in fact produce and Excel file with the test "foo" in cell A1. The problem is that I get the following error message from IE:

[image: error message displayed by Excel]

What am I doing wrong? How I produce the file so that it does not cause an error message to be displayed?

Comment: Should be application/vnd.ms-excel instead of application/vmd.ms-excel (vmd -> vnd)

Comment: Maxim, yes, you are correct. This does not solve the problem however. I am updating the code to reflect this correction.

Comment: If this is a duplicate question, would you please provide a link to where this question is answered? The linked question which is supposedly a duplicate does not ask "How I produce the file so that it does not cause an error message to be displayed?" and more importantly does not answer that question.

Comment: Here is an article claiming that this can be done http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/kaushikborah28/79Nick08302007171404PM/79Nick.aspx but it lacks a working sample.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is not an Excel workbook.

When Excel opens a file, it does not consider or trust file extension because it can be changed arbitrarily by the user - instead it opens any file and looks for certain patterns (for example, Excel 2007+ OOXML files begin with the characters `PK`. CSV files have commas at regular intervals, old Excel files have their own binary format and "magic words", etc)

In your case, Excel is opening the file, detecting it as HTML, and reading it as a HTML table and converts it into a spreadsheet for you. Your code isn't actually sending a "real" Excel workbook - so your MIME type is completely incorrect.

If you want something that will always "just work" I suggest letting the user download data in CSV format, which has the benefit of being cross-platform and openable in Microsoft Excel, Apple Numbers, OpenOffice Calc, and good ol' Notepad. Make sure you serve it as `text/csv`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't implicitly create an Excel file as an HTTP Response.  You basically have two options:

1. Create a response in a format that Excel can read, such as comma-delimited (CVS).
2. Use a server-side API to create an Excel file programmatically and send it back as an attachment.

If you choose the first option, you'll continue to get this pop-up when the file opens in Excel.  The file will open in Excel, however.

The second option will probably cost you money.  I used to work for a company called SoftArtisans who wrote an API called ExcelWriter that will do what you need:

http://www.officewriter.com/officewriter-free-evaluation.aspx

Their main competitor is Aspose, whose product is called Aspose.Cells.  I haven't used it personally but they have loyal customers of their own, so I assume the product is fine:

http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Aspose.Cells

Comment: Or use/learn the extremely free [OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) to [Generate Excel Workbooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh180830%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't disagree with that suggestion, especially if it's a simple workbook.  If you're wanting to write the xls file format, though, that's not an option.

Comment: For future readers, the above suggestions avoid using Office Interop. It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: @maniak1982 Why is that not an option? I've written many excel docs behind the scenes with the SDK. Granted, it uses the newer `.xlsx` file format, but that doesn't mean it can't be done.

Comment: The OOXML SDK is fine.  Automation using Office Interop (the APIs you use when you write VBA macros in Office) is not, for reasons given above.